# What is the name of the error correcting code which uses progressively finer "combs"?

Tags: error-correction

If I have `uint64` data, I can bitwise-AND it with:

- `0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF`
- `0xFFFF_FFFF_0000_0000`
- `0xFFFF_0000_FFFF_0000`
- `0xFF00_FF00_FF00_FF00`
- `0xF0F0_F0F0_F0F0_F0F0`
- `0xCCCC_CCCC_CCCC_CCCC`
- `0xAAAA_AAAA_AAAA_AAAA`

If I calculate the parity of those seven results, I am left with seven bits.

Assuming zero or one bit-flips in the data, these seven bits can be used to find:

- whether no bits have flipped, or
- which single bit has flipped (which can then be corrected).

What is the name of this error-correcting code?